# Why would my DAO return null when the Database Inspector shows a record?

Tags: java, sql, repository, android-room, dao

As you see from the image below, I am sending workoutExercise=20 to my Repository's updateWorkoutExercise function.

```
//Repository:
    public Completable updateWorkoutExercise(Long workoutExercise, String exerciseName) {
        WorkoutExercise we = workoutExerciseDAO.getWorkoutExercise(workoutExercise);
        Exercise e = exerciseDAO.getExerciseByName(exerciseName);
        we.exercise = e.id;
        return workoutExerciseDAO.update(we);
    }
```

I would expect to see the same result that my Database Inspector gives if I'm using the same SQL string.

```
//workoutExerciseDAO:
@Query("SELECT * FROM workoutExercises WHERE id = :workoutExercise LIMIT 1")
WorkoutExercise getWorkoutExercise(Long workoutExercise);
```

But my DAO returns a null. Why would that be?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case you got the above error, it turns out I had two databases. Database names, it appears, are case specific, and some of my code was accessing the old database.